# Create a facebook application programmatically

Tags: facebook, api

I'm trying to programmatically create an application in Facebook. I can do that with this:

https://www.facebook.com/connect/create_app.php?api_key=[key]&name=app_name

However, there's always a popup that says "Allow [Root App] to integrate Facebook functionality for you?" ... OK.

Is it possible for the "Root App" to create the application on the user's behalf without the popup via some previous permission which they have allowed, like stream_publish ...etc or maybe a session_token or ??

Someone said I can create child apps via "admin.setAppProperties" but couldn't get it working. I've also tried "FB.Connect.createApplication" and "Facebook.createApplication" but also failed.

Can anyone help? Maybe with some sample code.

Comment: Interesting question for sure !

Comment: An app that makes apps. You trying to put us out of work?  :)

Comment: Define "failed". There are such methods and they should work

Comment: I would be surprised if Facebook is okay with creating applications programmatically. That's just asking for them to be spammed with apps.

Comment: Do you have the documentation for /connect/create_app.php? Couldn't find it.

Comment: @Kai Chan did you manage to get this working? I've used Facebook.createApplication but its a bit messy. What was your 'almost got a solution to my problem now'??

Comment: @Kai Chan, I'm also wondering if you came up with a solution

Answer (score 6):

There used to be an API for this but I think it has been discontinued. You can see if you can hack it together from the information available here:

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/10/15/facebook-lets-you-easily-integrate-into-sites-and-widgets-with-new-create-application-api/

Answer (score 2):

Child applications (I believe they called them 'fourth party applications') intentionally need user interactions to create.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for https://www.facebook.com/connect/create_app.php?api_key=[key]&name=app_name is scarce to none. Are you able to access the API key of the newly created application somehow? Or set further app settings such as site-url?

I'm thinking you would need the user's permission to view `/accounts` then monitor before/after state to detect which one was created.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for the "Root App" to create the application on the
>   user's behalf without the popup via some previous permission which
>   they have allowed, like stream_publish ...etc or maybe a session_token
>   or ??

If you create a Facebook application that only pulls someone's profile information, and then you add new functionality that allows it to automatically post on people's walls; you would have to require the user to re-authenticate themselves to give you those extra permissions.

*It's hard to understand what you meant by that question.*