# Facebook programmatically application creation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I'm facing the situation where I need to programmatically create multiple Facebook Messenger Apps to different chatbots. Pretty much something like ManyChat and ChatFuel. Can someone shed some light on how is it possible?

There's a thread on it from 2011 but I've been uncessful on finding documentation on these old Facebook API's.

[Create a facebook application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264080/create-a-facebook-application-programmatically)

Thanks!

Comment: There is no API for that.

Comment: Don't be under the impression that those services you mentioned would necessarily be using an individual app id for each customer.

Comment: ManyChat and ChatFuel likely use just one application. The Messenger webhooks include the ID of the page the message is sent to, and thus you can run multiple pages on one app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API for this. As ceejayoz mentioned, ManyChat and ChatFuel just run one app and use their customer's account with the rights manage_pages and subscribed_apps to subscribe the app to the customer's page.

That said, there is just one endpoint where all traffic is delivered to and the software has to route every message to this endpoint accordingly to the right page (using receiver_id in the payload).

Keep in mind that while you want to run several apps in parallel, you have to approve all of them. Without this approval, the app can not be reached from customers.

For more insight, see the FB docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/?locale=en_US

And https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps